# css does not work on selected row of a tableview in order to change the text color

Tags: css, javafx, tableview, selected, textcolor

I assigned a css-file to a table view.
I want to change te background color of the selected row (which works) and the txt color (ewhich does not work).
I know that this problem has been covered but none of the answers I found and applied did work.
The background of a selected row turns from dark grey into light blue. 
The text color remains white (it should be black).
I am using the jre1.8.0_211.
It would be great if someone could help me. Thank you so much in advance.

I put the  '-fx-fill: black;' in the 'table-row-cell:selected{' part and tried '-fx-fill: black;
as some other variants from the net which I actually don't remember.
This is a part of the css-file:

```
.table-view .table-cell{
    -fx-text-fill: White;
    -fx-font-size: 14px;
}

.table-row-cell{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-table-cell-border-color, #616161;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-padding: 0.0em; /* 0 */
}

table-row-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color:  #CBDAFF;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 1;
    -fx-border-color: #b3c7dc;
}

.table-row-cell:selected .text {
    -fx-fill: black ;
}
```

No effects can be recognized concerning the text color of a selected row.

Answer (score 4):

this worked for me:

```
.table-view:focused .table-row-cell:selected .table-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works and you helped me a lot.